# How to manage input from multiple beats to centralized Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana-4, logstash-configuration, filebeat

I want to use Elastic Stack for log aggregation for fetching logs from 10 machines. I wish to install Filebeat on 10 machines & grab the logs from each machine and send it to a centralized Logstash server which is installed in a separate machine. In separate machine, Logstash Elasticsearch & Kibana is installed. I require Logstash as I want to do processing & parsing of data after gathering the logs using beats.

As per this architecture, I am facing some issues of identifying and parsing the logs. How to make logstash identify to collect logs from multiple beats server's at once? Can i specify multiple host in logstash-beats plugin so that logstash will parse all the logs from 10 machines at once?

Should i define separate document_type in all the 10 machines as part of Filebeat Configuration which can be later leveraged in Logstash so that I define multiple types (using wildcard - tomcat*) in filter plugin.

Sample Filebeat Configuration for Single Machine Setup:-

```
################### Filebeat Configuration Example #########################
############################# Filebeat ####################################
filebeat:
  prospectors:
    -
      paths:
        - /location/to/file/catalina.out
      document_type: tomcat1
      scan_frequency: 5s
      input_type: log

output:
  logstash:
    hosts: ["<host-of-the-machine-on-which-logstash-is-installed>:5044"]
  console:
    pretty: true
  shipper:
  logging:
  files:
    rotateeverybytes: 10485760 # = 10MB
```

This type of setup will be done on all 10 machines wherein value of document_type will only change.

Sample Logstash Configuration for Single Machine:-

```
input {
    beats   {
        host => "ip/of/machine/1"
        port => 5044
    }
}
filter {
    ........................
    ........................
    ........................
}
output{
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "localhost:9200"
        index => "logs-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

More ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Actually the `host` parameter for beats input plugin means `The IP address to listen on.` This is not the ip for filebat and actually not required at all.

So just specifying port to listen must be enough and I think the configuration you show will work. Logstash will listen logs from all 10 machines and will process them.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-beats.html#plugins-inputs-beats-host